# Agregação de dataframe no R

Tags: r

Boa noite. Tenho uma dúvida que certamente é das mais simples mas não consegui resolver. Gostaria, se possível, obter essa ajuda. Tenho o seguinte dataframe (imagem) e gostaria de totalizar esses dados considerando a variável (cod_v_BA). Ou seja,quero resumir esses dados utilizando como critério os agrupamentos exibidos pela variável em destaque, mantendo todas as demais variáveis visíveis no meu banco. Sei que temos a função summurize mas estou com dúvidas porque ela utiliza, dentre outros casos, a função soma como parametro mas no meu caso, as somas serão executadas em cada uma das demais variáveis que estão na sequencia do banco, tomando como referencia os agrupamentos gerados na variável cod_v_BA)
[image: Base de dados geral]

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Entendi. Me perdoe, mas como estou iniciando, acabei não conseguindo colocar o código e tive que recorrer à imagem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eis duas soluções.

Primeiro uma base de dados, já que na pergunta os dados estão como imagem.

```r
dados <- iris
names(dados)[1:4] <- sprintf("Ativ_%02d", 1:4)
names(dados)[5] <- "cod_v_BA"
head(dados)
#>   Ativ_01 Ativ_02 Ativ_03 Ativ_04 cod_v_BA
#> 1     5.1     3.5     1.4     0.2   setosa
#> 2     4.9     3.0     1.4     0.2   setosa
#> 3     4.7     3.2     1.3     0.2   setosa
#> 4     4.6     3.1     1.5     0.2   setosa
#> 5     5.0     3.6     1.4     0.2   setosa
#> 6     5.4     3.9     1.7     0.4   setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### R base

Com R base a melhor solução é provavelmente `aggregate`.

```r
aggregate(. ~ cod_v_BA,  dados, sum)
#>     cod_v_BA Ativ_01 Ativ_02 Ativ_03 Ativ_04
#> 1     setosa   250.3   171.4    73.1    12.3
#> 2 versicolor   296.8   138.5   213.0    66.3
#> 3  virginica   329.4   148.7   277.6   101.3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Pacote `dplyr`

Agrupam-se os dados e depois calculam-se a somas por grupo de todas as colunas que começam por `"Ativ"`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

dados %>%
  group_by(cod_v_BA) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Ativ"), sum))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   cod_v_BA   Ativ_01 Ativ_02 Ativ_03 Ativ_04
#>   <fct>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 setosa        250.    171.    73.1    12.3
#> 2 versicolor    297.    138.   213      66.3
#> 3 virginica     329.    149.   278.    101.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @JoaoPaulo [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)